# background image and color change on hover with duration

Tags: html, css, background, transition, duration

Welcome.
I'm trying to add color on background-image on hover with some duration. I already added color mask, but I've got a problem with time of animation. Can anyone tell me why transition-duration doesn't work here?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kamilm14/pysmzryn/

Here is my HTLM code:

```
   <table style="width: 510px; border: 0px;">
     <tr>
        <td class="scandic">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10px; height: 119px;">
        </td>
        <td class="stayinn">
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

And CSS:

```
.scandic {
width: 250px; height: 119px;
    background: url('http://oi61.tinypic.com/2dvlibt.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px 119px;
    border: 0;
}

.scandic:hover {
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,188,212,0.8), rgba(0,188,212,0.8)), url(http://oi61.tinypic.com/2dvlibt.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size:250px 119px;

}

.stayinn {
width: 250px; height: 119px;
    background-image: url('http://oi58.tinypic.com/35iztsh.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:250px 119px;
    border: 0;
}

.stayinn:hover {
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,188,212,0.8), rgba(0,188,212,0.8)), url(http://oi58.tinypic.com/35iztsh.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size:250px 119px;
}

.scandic, .stayinn {
     -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be caused by you using multiple backgrounds. Have you looked into using pseudo elements instead? They'll provide a cleaner markup and will allow you to quite quickly pick this up.

**Note**

prefixing transition isn't really needed anymore unless you're looking to [support really old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Here's a quick demo:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  /*required*/
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 200, 200, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  /*I've reduced this to a single line (prefixing isn't needed)!*/
}
div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Oh. Ty :D You inspired me to make it easier way: https://jsfiddle.net/kamilm14/5z2j0gpL/ :)